# Adjoint system associated to a linear system of PDEs

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjoint-operators

I am reading about adjoint systems of linear partial differential equations and appears the following example of a system over the domain $(a,b)\times (0,T)$, where $T>0$ and $a,\, b\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
f_t + a_1 g_x =0,
$$
$$g_t - a_2 g_{xx} + a_3 f_x + a_4 h_x =0,  $$
$$
h_t - a_5 h_{xx}+ a_6 g_x =0,
$$
where each $a_i$ is a real number. The adjoint system associated to the system above reads as

$$ - u_t - a_1 v_x =0, $$
$$ - v_t - a_2 v_{xx} - a_3 u_x - a_4 w_x =0, $$
$$ - w_t - a_5 w_{xx} - a_6 v_x =0.$$

**How could I obtain this adjoint system ? What is the procedure to get it ?**

Comment: You need a suitable definition of an inner product first in order to compute the adjoint, and also boundary conditions to ensure terms vanish (unless you are just considering the homogeneous part). What resource are you reading?

Comment: Also, are you sure the adjoint system is correct? I think you have your $a_{1}$ and $a_{3}$ mixed up, and your $a_{6}$ and $a_{4}$ mixed up.

Comment: @mattos is is a paper. Do you know some basic references where I can read about it?

Comment: Nayfeh 'Introduction to Perturbation Techniques' and Habersham 'Partial Differential Equations' both have stuff on this I believe. I'm writing an answer right now anyway. Can you link the paper so I can have a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your original system as $A \vec{f} = \vec{0}$ where $\vec{f} = (f,g,h)$ and

\begin{align}
A &= \begin{pmatrix}
\partial_{t} & a_{1} \partial_{x} & 0 \\
a_{3} \partial_{x} & \partial_{t} - a_{2} \partial_{xx} & a_{4} \partial_{x} \\
0 & a_{6} \partial_{x} & \partial_{t} - a_{5} \partial_{xx}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

is a matrix of disembodied derivative operators. Recall that $M$ is adjoint to $N$ if $\langle M x, y \rangle = \langle x, N y \rangle$ for a suitable notion of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. In this case, we want to use integration by parts and so we let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle = L^{1}$, though we will also consider $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ to be a projection (dot product) so we can solve the entire system simultaneously.

Computing $\langle A \vec{f}, \vec{u} \rangle$ where $\vec{u} = (u, v, w)$, $\Omega = (a, b) \times (0, T)$ and IBP stands for integration by parts

\begin{align}
0 &= \langle A \vec{f}, \vec{u} \rangle \quad \text{(as $A \vec{f} = \vec{0}$)} \\\\
&= \int_{\Omega} (A \vec{f}) \cdot \vec{u} \ dx dt \\\\
&=\int_{\Omega} \left[ (f_{t} + a_{1} g_{x}) u + (a_{3} f_{x} + g_{t} - a_{2} g_{xx} + a_{4} h_{x}) v + (a_{6} g_{x} + h_{t} - a_{5} h_{xx}) w \right] \ dx dt \\\\
&\underbrace{=}_{\text{IBP}} \text{(terms that need to be evaluated)} \\
&- \int_{\Omega} \left[ f u_{t} + g (a_{1} u_{x}) + f (a_{3} v_{x}) + g (v_{t} + a_{2} v_{xx}) + h (a_{4} v_{x}) + g (a_{6} w_{x}) + h (w_{t} + a_{5} w_{xx}) \right] dx dt \\\\
&= \text{(terms that need to be evaluated)} \\
&- \int_{\Omega} \left[ f (u_{t} + a_{3} v_{x}) + g (a_{1} u_{x} + v_{t} + a_{2} v_{xx} + a_{6} w_{x}) + h (a_{4} v_{x} + w_{t} + a_{5} w_{xx}) \right] dx dt \\\\
&= \text{(terms that need to be evaluated)} + \int_{\Omega} \vec{f} \cdot (B \vec{u}) \ dx dt \\\\
&= \text{(terms that need to be evaluated)} + \langle \vec{f}, B \vec{u} \rangle
\end{align}

where

\begin{equation}
B = \begin{pmatrix}
- \partial_{t} & - a_{3} \partial_{x} & 0 \\
-a_{1} \partial_{x} & - \partial_{t} - a_{2} \partial_{xx} & -a_{6} \partial_{x} \\
0 & -a_{4} \partial_{x} & - \partial_{t} - a_{5} \partial_{xx}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

which is almost the result you have written down, except the coefficients $a_{1}$ and $a_{3}$ are swapped, as are the $a_{4}$ and $a_{6}$ coefficients, which is a typo on your end or the papers. You also need to specify boundary and initial conditions on the functions to determine what happens to the evaluated terms.

Comment: I have a question about what is the situation if appears functions in the original system without partial derivatives, I put this issue in a new question. Do you know how proceed in this different case ?

Comment: Then it is exactly the same procedure as what I did above, except you don't need to integrate by parts because the term has no derivative. For example, if the first equation was $f_{t} + a_{1} g$ (no derivative on $g$ now) then you would have \begin{align} \int [ (f_{t} + a_{1} g) u + \text{extra terms }] dx dt &=  \int [f_{t} u + (a_{1} g) u + \text{extra terms }] dx dt \\&=\text{terms to be evaluated} + \int [f (-u_{t}) + g (a_{1} u )+\text{extra terms }] dx dt \\&=\text{terms to be evaluated} + \langle \vec{f}, C \vec{u} \rangle \end{align} where $C$ is slightly different from the $B$ above

Comment: why the extra terms inside the integral are not multiplied by $u$?, I mean:
$\begin{align} \int [ (f_{t} + a_{1} g) u + \text{extra terms }u] dx dt &=  \int [f_{t} u + (a_{1} g) u + \text{extra terms }u] dx dt \\&=\text{terms to be evaluated} + \int [f (-u_{t}) + g (a_{1} u )+\text{extra terms }u] dx dt \\&=\text{terms to be evaluated} + \langle \vec{f}, C \vec{u} \rangle \end{align}$

Comment: @Newinmaths Only the first equation in the system is multiplied by $u$, the second equation is multiplied by $v$ etc. See my original post.

Comment: yes, I understood that, but my comments is on the "extra terms" inside the integral, these are multiplied by $u, v$ and $w$ respectively, right ?

Comment: The 'extra terms' refer to the dot product of the other two equations from your original system with their corresponding entries from the vector $\vec{u}$, which is $v$ and $w$ only. So the 'extra terms' are $$(a_{3} f_{x} + g_{t} - a_{2} g_{xx} + a_{4} h_{x}) v + (a_{6} g_{x} + h_{t} - a_{5} h_{xx}) w$$

Comment: thank so much !

Comment: What happen if we change the first equation: $f_t + a_1 g_x =0$ by 
$f_t + a_1 g_x  + f_x(c^-)=0,$ where $c\in (a,b)$ ? is necessary to put $ f_x(c^-)$ in its adjoint form also ?